# Django migration command hanging on Heroku even without actual new migration

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

We are running our stack on Heroku. We are using Django 2.2 with a Postgres 11 DB. Our build pipeline (Github Actions) pushes to Heroku (`git push https://git.heroku.com...`) and immediately afterwards runs the migrations (`heroku run python manage.py migrate --app heroku-app-name`). All of that was working with a Postgres 9.6 database and is still working in our staging environment (Postgres 11). Now with production being on Postgres 11, the django migrate command is just stuck and doesn't produce any output, even so there are no actual migrations to apply.

The only differences between our production setup and our staging setup are a follower/slave in production attached to the master DB and "production workload".

In order to fix that deployment I have to run a

```
heroku pg:killall -a heroku-app-name
heroku restart -a heroku-app-name
```

At this point the migrations task in the build pipeline fails.

and afterwards migrations can be applied manually without problems:

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate --app heroku-app-name
```

So for some reason the migrations command is "waiting" for something, some database lock or whatever, yet I cannot put my finger on it. Especially odd for me is the fact that its also stuck where no migrations are to applied. Why would it be stuck there?

Comment: We face exactly the same issue since we migrated Postgres9 to Postgres11. No resolution found yet.

Comment: Ok so its not just us. Ill keep you posted if I find a solution.

Comment: I am waiting internaly a new occurence to analyze the lock itself. If you already have this, can you list the lock in the database ? Maybe you will see something at this level.

Comment: I plan to use this: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/view-pg-locks.html

Comment: We have solved the issue now for us. I left a reply below. The thing that tipped me off were seeing DB backups failing for dates that we deployed new versions. See below for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the solution. There are actually three things coming together.

1. We trigger a DB backup before running any migrations. We only do so in Production and not on staging, which was the reason why our staging environment had no issues while production had.
2. A DB migration (even so it looks like there is nothing to apply) is actually running some commands (besides regular SELECT, UPDATE, INSERTS). E.g. in our case there was a CREATE EXTENSION ... IF NOT EXISTS always executed at the beginning.
3. While it was possible with Postgres 9.6 to have a backup job running in parallel (I don't know what heroku is using under the hood, yet I assume a noraml `pg_dump`) the backup job on Postgres 11 (and others?) has now a more exclusiv lock on some operations. I assume that that a CREATE EXTENSION ... IF NOT EXISTS (even so the extension already exists) cannot be executed while having a backup job running in parallel.

(I am sure there are some Postgres internas missing to explain this more correctly)

As a result of these three things, the DB blocks the migrate operation, waiting for the backup job to finish. I have moved the daily backup job to a different time and reconfigured our pipeline to wait for the "pre-deploy"-backup to finish first.

Comment: We are not in the same situation, I think for us it is just the load on the database while doing the migration. As you stated, probably the locks are a bit more exclusive. We'll find a way to reduce the load during the migrate. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: I am sorry that its not helping you. I hope you will find the cause for your problem too!